# Listar Dispositivos Interface Humana usando C#

Tags: c#

Estou enfrentando dificuldade em descobrir como listar e acessar a um dispositivo no PC, lembrando que apesar da entrada ser USB ele é reconhecido como um *HID* dispositivo de interface humana tipo mouse ou teclado.

Bom já vi vários e vários site o mais promissor que encontrei seria usando um *select* com `ManagementObjectSearcher` dai acessaria a classe `win32` porém não encontrei nenhuma opção nela que me retorna os *HIDs* ou pelo menos não encontrei a forma correta.

Answer (score 1):

Por exemplo:

Se for para imprimir o nome de todas `USB` locais do seu Computador seria:

```cs
System.Management.ManagementClass usbClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_USBHub");
System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection usbCollection = usbClass.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject usb in usbCollection)
{

    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", 
        "HID".Contains((string)usb.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID")), 
        usb.GetPropertyValue("name"),
        usb.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"));
}
```

Comment: então isso já tinha visto e conseguido implementar..porém preciso listar dispositivos de interface humana se entrar no gerenciador de dispositivos você vai ver que são diferentes os dispositivos de interface humana dos usb, apesar de ambos serem entrada usb

Comment: @Tamires, eu fiz uma edição, por favor teste esse código e verifique se sai em algumas das linhas true ou false (no inicio), se for true é o que você procura!, por favor fico no aguardo?